# I want to fully switch to Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, format, convert

Right now I have windows and Ubuntu on my laptop. I don't use Windows anymore. But it still has the majority of my hard drive space. How do I fully switch to Ubuntu. Also. It is apparently badly corrupted, someone told me.

Here is my screen shot of `gparted`

[image]

Comment: Is the hard-drive 'badly corrupted'?

Comment: To add to @Pieter comment, what is corrupted ? Windows ? Ubuntu ? the whole drive ?

Comment: Please make a screenshot of `gparted`, upload it somewhere and post a link. Then we will be able to advise how to remove Windows.

Comment: http://imgur.com/BVQ6tcA @Pilot6

Answer (score 1):

Best option to remove windows and expand Ubuntu is, boot to a live Ubuntu DVD/USB, and run

```
sudo gparted
```

Now right click your windows partition and delete it so it is empty space (back up anything you need first as it is now gone) and click the green tick to apply.

Now you can right click on the Ubuntu partition and choose `resize/move` here you can expand Ubuntu in to the rest of the blank space.

Now just click the green tick to apply the partition and wait for it to finish, (could take a while) and Ubuntu will be the only OS with all the space.

You may also need to reinstall `grub` depending on where you had it installed, from a live DVD/USB open a terminal and run

```
sudo grub install /dev/sda
```

Assuming your Ubuntu drive is `sda`.

In the event you still can't boot, [use boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), to fix `grub`

Comment: OP may also need to re-install grub if start sector of `/` is moved.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest approach would be:

1. Backup your important data from Ubuntu and Windows
2. Do a complete new installation including Windows disc spaces

Comment: While this would work, reinstalling the OS is very rarely the `easiest` solution and is a massive inconvenience for most users, in this instance it is not required at all.

Comment: Please tell a newbe to delete windows partition, resize his current ones, resize filesystem and remote the Windowsstuff out of the MBR. He will get lost -- even he/she will learn a lot it will be frustrating.Even with gparted I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Like I said its not that your wrong, but, reinstalling is a big undertaking for many users as they have there system set up how they like it, with there programs and files and any issues they had ironed out, there is a lot more too a reinstall than just the installing. The Gparted method takes like ten clicks and has graphics clearly stating what is going on, it IS the very easiest way to perform complex hdd manipulations, much easier than reinstalling.

Comment: Also how do you know the OP is a noob ? It may be there first post here but the clearly state they got to the point of not even needing Windows anymore, this suggests a competent user. Finally I did not do the down vote if thats the point of the comment, as I said this WOULD work, so I don't think it should get down voted. My objection is only that reinstall is not as easy as it may be for you as for others.

Comment: I still don't think so. There are a lot of possible issues running gparted the user might not be aware of. E.g. is there a full disc encryption. Also you will get an issue if Windows is /dev/sda1 and gparted needs to move / (or kind of weird partition at the end) ... I still believe, doing a backup of maybe ~  and reinstalling a fast and nicer solution.

Comment: This being said: gparted way is not bad in general and will in most cases really work. But if not, it will fail really hard.